# Interpretation of a one cluster solution using the EM cluster algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, weka

I'm trying to use the EM cluster algorithm, provided by the software Weka, to classify my data and it only finds one cluster.

- Could I interpret this as there are no ways to distinguish the instances in my sample?

This is a result that is coherent with others analysis  that I'm doing to the data, but I don't know if I could use a cluster analysis to state that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two assumptions here: 1) Weka's finding the number of clusters (k) without issues, and 2) I believe EM uses mixtures of Gaussians which means the clusters need to be round/elliptical.

So, given that Weka's algorithm is finding the best k, the answer would be that using round/elliptical clusters, the most likely clustering is one group. That doesn't mean that your data doesn't cluster at all (using other shapes, essentially).